# Question on Summation of a equation

Tags: summation

Find $$\sum_{x= 1/2}^{25 / 2} x^3 + 3x + 2.$$ Are there any simpler methods to solve this summation ? I will be thankful to any helps.

Counting is in the format of ${1 \over2}, 1, {3 \over2},....   $

Comment: Is the idea that $x$ takes values $\frac12, \frac32, \frac52,\ldots$, or that it takes values $\frac12, 1, \frac32, 2, \frac52,\ldots$?

Comment: @MJD just a second guys I am going over the question again because there was no information on the counting and it is meaningless if we don't define the counting.

Comment: Assuming $x$ grows as $\frac12,\frac22,\frac32 \cdots$  put $y=2x,$ the summation will become $$\frac18\sum_{1\le y\le 25}y^3+\frac32\sum_{1\le y\le 25}y+\frac12\sum_{1\le y\le 25}1$$

Comment: @MJD it is in the format of 1/2, 1, 3/2, ...

Answer (score 3):

Put $\frac y2 = x$.  Then the lower limit, which was $x=\frac12$, becomes $\frac y2=\frac12$, so $y=1$, and the upper limit, which was $x=\frac{25}2$, becomes $\frac y2=\frac{25}2$, so $y=25$.  We now want to sum $y$ from 1 to 25:

$$\sum_{y=1}^{25}\left(\frac18y^3 + \frac32y + 2\right) \\
= \frac18\sum_{y=1}^{25} y^3 + \frac32\sum_{y=1}^{25} y + \sum_{y=1}^{25}2
$$

Do you know how to evaluate the three sums separately?

(The important thing to check here it that we didn't somehow mess up the sums by changing the index from $x$ to $y$.  There are 25 terms in the sum now, and there should have been 25 in the sum before.  You said that is correct ($\frac12, 1, \frac32,\ldots \frac{25}2$ is 25 terms) so this substitution is correct. If the sum before had had only 13 terms ($\frac12,\frac32,\ldots \frac{25}2$ is only 13 terms) then new summation would not be the same.)

Comment: Yes I do. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: @MJD This sum equals to 13250. However, I computed the summation given in this question with Wolfram Alpha it computes as 59189/8. I am not sure what kind of counting does  Wolfram Alpha use ?

Comment: I calculated the answer by hand (pen and paper) using the lower formula in $y$, and also by a small computer program using the original formula in $x$, and both answers came out the same, and they did not match either of the results you gave.  I am not sure what you put into Wolfram Alpha either.  I suggest that you check your arithmetic.

Comment: @MJD http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+j%5E3+%2B+3j+%2B+2%2C+j%3D1%2F2+to+25%2F2

Comment: 59189/8 is the sum when the index runs over $\frac12, \frac32, \frac52,\ldots$.

Comment: @MJD yes you are right that is why I said I am not sure if Wolfram Alpha uses the same index here. However, with the index here which is 1/2, 1, ... still I obtain 13250. I computed each sum separately like how you separated each sum.

Comment: Yes I did have an error. What I got is 13.740,625. What was the output you obtained ?

Comment: That's what I get.